# Can we say that $\tau_1 = \tau_2\ $?

Tags: general-topology

> Let $X$ be a non-empty set. Let $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ be two topologies on $X.$ If there exists a homeomorphism $f : (X, \tau_1) \longrightarrow (X,\tau_2)$ then can we say that $\tau_1 = \tau_2\ $?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 3):

Take $X = \{1,2\}$, $\tau_1 = \{\varnothing,\{1\},X\}$, $\tau_2 = \{\varnothing,\{2\},X\}$ and the map $f : X \to X$ such that $f(1)=2$ and $f(2) = 1$.

Comment: What about the linear homeomorphism between normed linear spaces where the underlying set is fixed for both the spaces? Does it preserve the underlying topologies?